# "tag start is not closed" error in AndroidManifest

Tags: android

I'm making a small app to copy a link of a video from the intent menu, but when i try to compile the app, i get the error "tag start is not closed" in my androidmanifest:

the error appears at the end of line 10. Thanks in advance for any replies!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.reshare.copyurl">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="rtsp"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:scheme="content"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/mpeg4"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/mp4"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/3gp"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/3gpp"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/3gpp2"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/webm"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/avi"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/sdp"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter> !-- HTTP live support -->;
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:mimeType="audio/x-mpegurl"/>
                <data android:mimeType="audio/mpegurl"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-mpegurl"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Nongthonbam Tonthoi's answer is right but may I ask you which IDE you are using? Android Studio will show you that there's something wrong and I think eclipse too.

Comment: I'm using android studio, latest stable build

Comment: OK Android Studio marks all errors! So if you get such error again, take a close look again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing **>**

Change this part:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

by adding a **>** like this:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
```

Comment: Thanks! It's my first time with android development and first time working with xml, i need to get used to the syntax it seems